# Mongoose, update sub-document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider the following schema

```
Var Schema = new Schema({
  username: {Type: String},
  ...
  ...
  contacts: {
    email: {Type: String},
    skype: {Type: String}
    }
  })
```

As every user can state only one email and skype i don't want to use array with contacts.

Discarding DB queries and error handling i try to do something like

```
// var user is the user document found by id
var newValue = 'new@new.new';
user['username'] = newValue;
user['contacts.$.email'] = newValue;
console.log(user['username']); // logs new@new.new    
console.log(user['contacts.$.email']); // logs new@new.new
user.save(...);
```

No error occurs and username gets successfully updated, while contacts sub-document is still empty.
What do i miss there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `$` index from your path as `contacts` isn't an array, and use the `set` method instead of trying to directly manipulate the properties of `user` using a path:

```
var newValue = 'new@new.new';
user.set('contacts.email', newValue);
user.save(...);
```

Or you can modify the embedded `email` field directly:

```
var newValue = 'new@new.new';
user.contacts.email = newValue;
user.save(...);
```

If it's not just a typo in your question, your other problem is that you need to use `type` and not `Type` in your schema definition.  So it should be:

```
var Schema = new Schema({
  username: {type: String},
  ...
  ...
  contacts: {
    email: {type: String},
    skype: {type: String}
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, user.set(key, newValue) works for me. However, note that direct modification with user.contacts.email = newValue has no effect.

Comment: Then something's wrong with your schema definition.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Yep, my schema is defined exactly as yours, type defined with lower case 't'. Sure, there were typos in original question. Anyway, user.set() works well and is even better in my case, as it requires less code.

Comment: +1 the set method helped me save new fields to a sub-document that is only defined as an Object in my user schema.  user.email = newValue saves just fine since it was described in my schema, but user.mobileDevice.phoneNumber = newValue would not save.  I had to use the set method:  user.set('mobileDevice.phoneNumber', newValue) to get the data to persist in the database.